# Do you get rating points if the other player just leaves an online game and loses on time?

Tags: rating, online-chess

Some sites, eg chessbase,  seem to have players that won't resign but either just leave for coffee until their clock runs out, or else they wait a minute then start another game so you have to ask the arbiter to declare the game won for you.

Not much we can do about impolite players, but ChessBase does not show any points won in this case. Today I beat a much higher rated player in 9 moves so I can understand their annoyance at playing like a patzer who just learned the moves today and their action was to stall a bit then just disconnect from this game while their clock still ran.

I got the arbiter to decide this time, but sometimes you have to wait until the entire clock runs down in case they come back at the very end to move and hope you left and your clock runs out.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't played on Chessbase for quite some time, but generally loss on time through disconnect is still a loss and loses rating accordingly. Otherwise too many people would just disconnect, obviously.

Lichess punishes people who let the time run out with a ban (after several such incidents), so it might be less of a problem there.

Comment: Small exception: Lichess, chess.com and probably most other sites let you "abandon games" with no rating loss before you make your first move. You will still get hit with quitter warnings/bans if you do that too often, though.

Comment: @Annatar  I find a lot of people abort when they see the rating is too high/low and they are afraid of losing/not winning any points.